# Incorrect Time showing on frontend

Tags: 7, datetime

I have installed the [Date Module](https://drupal.org/project/date) and added a date field to one of my content types, the widget I'm using is `Popup Calendar`. The problem I'm facing is that when I choose a date it seems to get stored and displayed correctly in the administration, but at the frontend the date is shown with two hours added to it.

For example if I set the fields value to `2014-12-12 10:00:00` its displayed as `2014-12-12 12:00:00` when I'm visiting a frontend page.

Like some of the comments have pointed out this might be because the frontend is displaying a visitors local time, but still I don't get why the time differance is two hours, when the differance between Findland and Sweden is only one hour.

I guess this has do do with some `Regional settings` or similar.

Comment: Are you using any `time format` to display time in front end.

Comment: How do you mean? I'm just use `node_load()` in a template and then using `print $node->field_time[$node->language][0]['value'];` to display the content.

Comment: I mean setting `date format` for date from admin section.

Comment: Looks like a typical timezone issue. Is your site's or user's timezone 2 hours off from GMT?

Comment: @Mołot - Yes it is. It's set to `Europe/Helsinki: <time> +0200` and the pre selected country is `Finland`. I'm using the site from `Sweden`. But I have also unchecked that user may change their timezone.

Comment: So, your admin interface shows you GMT, and user interface shows your local time? Makes sense to me. But should be described better. And it may be off the other way if your server is using local time and not the GMT. Don't know how to "solve" it, but I'm glad we at least probably identified the issue.

Comment: @Mołot - What I still don't understand is why the time differance is 2 hours between the backend and the frontend? The time differance between Findland and Sweden are only 1 hour.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe try this:

```
// Example: Assume we have a node with nid 1 which contains a single
// language-neutral date field named field_date.
$node = node_load(1);
$date = $node->field_date[LANGUAGE_NONE][0];

// Create a date object.
$date_object = new DateObject($date['value'], new DateTimeZone($date['timezone_db']));
// Convert from the database time zone to the user's time zone.
$date_object->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone($date['timezone']));

// Example: Print a formatted date.
print date_format_date($date_object, 'custom', 'Y m d');
```

Source: [Convert a date field to the correct time zone](http://dropbucket.org/node/559)

Answer (score 1):

If you're printing the date yourself, you could try loading the date with the given timezone to see what's returned.

```
// Just for fun, load a node that you know has the date field.
$node = node_load($nid);

// Grab the date value and timezone.
$date_value = $node->field_time['und'][0]['value'];

// For testing, try both the field timezone, and the server default.
$date_timezone = $node->field_time['und'][0]['timezone'];
$default_timezone = variable_get('date_default_timezone', '');

// Produce the new date.
$date = new DateTime($date_value, new DateTimeZone($date_timezone));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i') . '\n';

$date = new DateTime($date_value, new DateTimeZone($default_timezone));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i');    

// If you use Devel, just dpm it and see what you get back.
dpm($date);
```

Comment: When I'm doing the above I get `2014-02-12 08:00:00+02:00` and in the backend the same fields shows `2014-02-12 10:00:00`. Using `date_format($date, 'd.m.Y H:i');` I receive `2014-02-12 08:00:00`?

Comment: @KristerAndersson I updated my answer. Try using the field timezone as well as the site default timezone. (I'm not sure if they're both set or not). You could also try Drupal's [date_default_timezone](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!date!date_api!date_api.module/function/date_default_timezone/7) to see if it's based on the user?